# Loop through list of dataframes in R to take set difference

Tags: r, list, loops, set-difference

I'm hoping to take the set difference between 40 dataframes (10 years of data each with 4 quarters) starting with the second quarter of my first year and comparing it to the first quarter of my first year, all the way to my last quarter. I have all my dataframes in a list, but can't figure out the loop.

```
short <- list(q4_17, q1_18, q2_18, q3_18, q4_18)

for(i in short)
{j=i+1
new<- j %>%
filter(PATID %in% setdiff(j,i)$PATID)
}
```

I'm getting the error: Error in FUN(left, right): nun-numeric argument to binary operator.

Thanks for any suggestions. I would try to put my dataframes up but the code is on a remote desktop and difficult to get off.

Comment: You are missing some basic concepts here. In `for (i in short)`, you are iterating through the elements of a list called short, not their indexes. So when you try the command `i +`, you are trying to sum a numeric element (1) with a non-numeric (q4_17 in the first iteration).

Comment: If we want to loop through the indexes of the elements of the list, we may want to use `for i in (seq_along(short)) {...}`

Comment: Also `x %>% fun(y)` is evaluated as `fun(x, y)`, but it is meaningless to have `j` as the first argument of `filter()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of that error

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments above, two more problems:

1. You overwrite `new` which each pass of the `for` loop, so you will only benefit from the last pass, all previous passes will be silently discarded.
2. `i+1` (treating it as an index) works up until `i` indicates the last frame within `short`, at which point the "next frame in `short`" is an indexing *error*.

To appease both issues, we can do either of these, assuming that the setdiff/filter code actually does everything you need.

```r
## still a for loop
out <- list()
for (j in seq_along(short)[-1]) {
  i <- j - 1
  new <- short[[j]] %>%
    filter(PATID %in% setdiff(short[[j]], short[[i]])$PATID)
  out <- c(out, list(new))
}
out <- do.call(rbind, out)

## new: lapply
out <- lapply(seq_along(short)[-1], function(j) {
  short[[j]] %>%
    filter(PATID %in% setdiff(short[[j]], short[[j-1]])$PATID)
})
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

Judging by what you may be doing, I feel there is a better way to do this setdiff/filter part.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't quite understanding the difference between j and short[[j]], but makes sense. I'm basically looking through claims data by quarter for anyone diagnosed with this particular condition each quarter. I'm excluding individuals who were diagnosed with the condition in the previous quarter (though this exclusion criteria may change to in the previous 2 quarters). I am generally sure that there is always a better way to code compared to what I come up with lol